# Pass a vector from Matlab to Scala Class

Tags: java, matlab, scala, vector

I have a problem with Scala and passing a double vector from MATLAB to my Scala class.

Suppose that we have an Scala class of this form:

```
class MyClass {

def myMethod(x: Seq[Double]): Double = {
    val methodValue = for(i <- x.indices) yield { math.pow( x(i),2.0) }
    methodValue.sum
    }

}
```

> I've previously compiled this, matched java versions of my Matlab and JRE, and what ever needed

.

> I have tested Seq[Double], Array[Double] and Vector[Double], but no progress was achieved

.

And now I want to call this class within MATLAB and give it a desired row vector and get it's sum of squares value.

For this I wrote this mfile in Matlab:

```
clc, clear, close all

javaaddpath(pwd)
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\scala\lib\scala-library.jar')
javaclasspath('-dynamic')

newInstanceOfClass = MyClass
newInstanceOfClass.myMethod([1 2 3 4])
```

But I get an Error saying:

> No method 'myMethod' with matching signature found for
>   class 'MyClass'.

**I don't know how to pass a simple vector to this Scala class. Can anybody help me with this?**

> I also tried to use Matlab's javaArray to solve the problem but even that didn't work

Comment: Just wondering: You are sure that Matlab supports calling **Scala** methods/classes?

Comment: You might want to try changing MyClass to an object. There's no reason that I can see for myMethod to be an instance method (which would essentially take two parameters: this and the Seq[Double]).

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure MATLAB will run Scala classes. And I successfully ran a simple "Hello World" class with no input arguments. My problem is just with passing a vector of inputs to my Class which produces signature mismatch errors.

Comment: @Phasmid: Changing a class to an object does not help to solve the main problem. It only changes how you call that object or class from Matlab initially. Rest of the job is the same. We still need to pass a vector and even in the object form we get a signature mismatch error. (I've tested both of these forms)

Comment: Have you tried declaring x as Any and then printing the class of x? That should help you figure out what kind of an object Matlab is passing in.

Comment: Have you tried `Array[Int]`?

Comment: @Phasmid: Yes, and in prints 'class [D'  in Matlab Command Window for any passing vector like [1 2 3 4]

Comment: @Jasper-M: As told before I need Array[Double] to be passed. and even using this didn't help :(

Comment: Then `Array[scala.Double]` should work. `class [D` means it's an array of doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I **solved** this problem:

First I changed my Scala Class as follows:

```
class MyClass {

def myMethod(x: Array[java.lang.Double]): Double = {
    val methodValue = for(i <- x.indices) yield { math.pow( x(i),2.0) }
    methodValue.sum
    }

}
```

> I used `java.lang.Double` format to make the `Array[java.lang.Double]` instead of `Array[Double]` which was in fact `Array[scala.Double]`.

Finally in my Matlab script I converted the desired vector to `javaArray` [look Matlab documentation for this] and then normally could run Scala Class from Matlab Mfile :)